# Using while loop to print Ascii Table with 10 characters per line

Tags: c

I'm at a very basic level of C programming: I can print out an ASCII table.

The problem is printing out 10 of the ASCII characters per line, e.g.:

```
characters 1-10 (newline)
characters 10-20... 
and so on up to 255
```

```c
int main() {

   int i;
   while (i <= 255) {
       printf("%c", i);
       i = i + 1;
   }    

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Be careful. You didn't initilized `i`.

Comment: ASCII defined for 0 to 127, not 
"and so on up to 255".

Answer (score 3):

the following proposed code

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. also labels each line
4. makes use of `isprint()` from `ctype.h` to determine if outputs current character or outputs a '.'

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    for( int i = 0; i<256; i++ )
    {
        if( !( i%10 ) )
        {
            printf( "\n%3d thru %3d ", i, i+9 );
        }

        if( isprint( i ) )
        {
            putchar( i );
        }
        else
        {
            putchar( '.' );
        }
   }    
}
```

The output from the above code is:

```
000 thru 009 ..........
010 thru 019 ..........
020 thru 029 ..........
030 thru 039 .. !"#$%&'
040 thru 049 ()*+,-./01
050 thru 059 23456789:;
060 thru 069 <=>?@ABCDE
070 thru 079 FGHIJKLMNO
080 thru 089 PQRSTUVWXY
090 thru 099 Z[\]^_`abc
100 thru 109 defghijklm
110 thru 119 nopqrstuvw
120 thru 129 xyz{|}~...
130 thru 139 ..........
140 thru 149 ..........
150 thru 159 ..........
160 thru 169 ..........
170 thru 179 ..........
180 thru 189 ..........
190 thru 199 ..........
200 thru 209 ..........
210 thru 219 ..........
220 thru 229 ..........
230 thru 239 ..........
240 thru 249 ..........
250 thru 259 ......
```

You may want to modify the proposed code, such that:

1. it does not output an initial blank line
2. it stops the last label at 255 rather than 259
3. does not print leading '0's
4. does not print the labels

Answer (score 2):

Amending the previous answer it is not good to print non ascii chars as the console (terminal) behaviour can be weird. Print something else instead - for example dot,

```
#define MINCHAR 32
#define MAXCHAR 127

int main() {

   int i = 0;
   while(i<=255) {

       putchar((i >= MINCHAR && i <= MAXCHAR) ? i : '.');
       if(!(i % 10) && i) putchar('\n');
       i = i + 1;
   }    
   putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: UV for the "not good to print non ascii (or control) chars".  Alternative `if(i%10 == 9) putchar('\n');`

Comment: Warning you write the character _DEL_, _MAXCHAR_ must be 126 or more readable `'~'` (and `' '` more readable that 32 too even we know we are in ASCII). Else what about to replace  `(i >= MINCHAR && i <= MAXCHAR)` by `isgraph(i) || (i == ' ')` to also be compatible with non ASCII ?

Comment: @chux yes `if(i%10 == 9) putchar('\n');` before to increase _i_ (or `if(i++%10 == 9) putchar('\n');`) is a very best way

Comment: @bruno Interesting thought about "be compatible with non ASCII".  Had code been sourced with EBCDIC, yet still needed to "print Ascii Table", using 32, 126 rather than `' '`, `'~'` is the right approach.  Hmmm. yet `putchar(i);` woudl be amiss.  Oh well, so much for cross encoding support.

Comment: @chux not sure to understand your remark, but to clarify mine I proposed _isgraph_ as a way to test if a character is printable whatever the code by the compiler etc, so for memory in a general scope greater than the current, just that

Comment: @bruno Note: Could use `isprint(i))` instead of `isgraph(i) || (i == ' ')`.

Comment: @chux ah yes, very true, I missed it ^^

Answer (score 1):

So if you want afte every 10 character a new line, this code should work.

```
int main() {

   int i = 0;
   while(i<=255) {

       printf("%c", i);
       if(i % 10 == 0)
       printf("\n");

       i = i + 1;

   }    

   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: it will not print 10 chars in line. First one will be zero chars, another will vary (for exmple if `i` will be `'\n'` or `'\r'`